# System.OutOfMemoryException occurred in SharpDX.ni.DLL

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, sharpdx, xaudio2

I'm trying to create a windows phone app with multiple sounds playing simultaneously. For that I'm using SharpDX library.

```
        private XAudio2 xAudio;
        private MasteringVoice masteringVoice;
        private AudioBuffer buffer;
        private SourceVoice PlaySound(string strPath)
        {
            try
            {

                if (masteringVoice == null)
                {
                    xAudio = new XAudio2();
                    masteringVoice = new MasteringVoice(xAudio);
                }
                using (var nativeFileStream = new NativeFileStream(strPath, NativeFileMode.Open, NativeFileAccess.Read, NativeFileShare.Read))
                {
                    using (SoundStream stream = new SoundStream(nativeFileStream))
                    {
                        var waveFormat = stream.Format;

                        buffer = new AudioBuffer
                        {
                            Stream = stream.ToDataStream(),
                            AudioBytes = (int)stream.Length,
                            Flags = BufferFlags.EndOfStream
                        };

                        var sourceVoice = new SourceVoice(xAudio, waveFormat, true);

                        sourceVoice.SubmitSourceBuffer(buffer, stream.DecodedPacketsInfo);

                        if (buffer != null)
                        {
                            GC.SuppressFinalize(buffer);
                        }

                        return sourceVoice;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

After some count of playing sounds it throws an System.OutOfMemoryException exception at line buffer = new AudioBuffer. How can I fix this issue, and free memory?

Comment: Stream = stream.ToDataStream(),  where is that stream disposed?

Comment: How can I dispose it?

Comment: can you put a using around buffer =like using (AudioBuffer buffer = new AudioBuffer(..)) {  .. ciode here }

Comment: @aagha you call dispose? Ever learned the basics of C# unmanaged resource handling? You can also use USING - for automatic disposing. Because that is what using does. And never ever call suppress finalizer like that - I think you just efficiently turned OFF garbage collection for the buffer totally. Not smart.

Comment: AudioBuffer doesn't implement interface System.IDisposable, so I can't put it in using()

Comment: I'm curious to know where you got this `SupressFinalize` from. Especially since `buffer` can never be null, so I guess you copy&pasted that from somewhere, in a different context. Anyway, I'm not used to SharpDX, but if I trust this link then you need to call `DestroyVoice` on your `SourceVoice` when you're done with it: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58530/how-to-correctly-dispose-a-sourcevoice-once-its-finished